# Tried implementing implicit intents but it doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to android development and I am currently learning implicit intents. I was implementing url opener but my app keeps on crashing. I did everything according to the tutorial but still getting same error. I am attaching my main_activity.kt, manifest.xml and the error file below. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

```kt
package com.example.intents

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var searchBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.searchbtn)
        var eTv = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.eTv)

        var url: String = eTv.text.toString()

        var it: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        it.data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(it)

    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intents">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Intents">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
2021-08-11 09:03:31.012 15235-15235/com.example.intents E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.intents, PID: 15235
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intents/com.example.intents.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3374)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3513)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2241)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1895)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5205)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5163)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5534)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5502)
        at com.example.intents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7804)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1318)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
```

Comment: Add URL validation. URL must be start with `http://`

Comment: @Sniffer  var Url = "http://www." + url. Tried doing it but now it only searches for " http://www.". It's not taking the text from the editText.

Comment: Please comment your full URL here...

Comment: @Sniffer  var url: String = eTv.text.toString()
        var Url = "http://www.$url.org"

Comment: Your URL is in invalid format

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the text (url) on Edittext in xml file?. Because here you are just passing the text from edit text in onCreate() function which will be called as soon as the activity launches. If you haven't set the text in xml file then it must be null. First of all start the intent on click listener and also wrap the intent in try- catch block as it can throw MalformedUrlException if the url is wrong.
Like,

```
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).setOnClickListener {
        try {
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).also {
                it.data = Uri.parse("https://localhost:8080/")
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }catch (e: MalformedURLException){
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this , "Enter valid URL" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```